# disable a jQuery .toggle() method

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a way to disable a `.toggle()` attached to a div

```
if (condition) {
    $("#div").toggle(
        function() {
            do this
        },
        function() {
            do that
        }
    );
}
else {

    // How do I achieve this?
    $("#div").disableToggle(

    );
}
```

More explanation:

This is a map application. The `toggle` in question is bound to an image button. The map loads at zoom level 4. The user zooms in, and the button in question becomes active only when the user is zoomed in more than zoom level 6. Once the user zooms out to less than level 6, I want the toggle button to become inactive again.

Comment: The best way is to unbind the `click` events that toggle adds. I'd post an answer, but I'm out of time right now.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using toggle() in this case; toggle() uses an internal counter and it's very likely to get borked if you try turning it on and off.

Comment: It is not that I am trying to turn `toggle()` off. It is more like I want to disable it on some condition. The app is dependent on a certain map zoom level. Only at the correct zoom should the toggle be active. When the user moves out of the zoom range, toggle should deactivate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just unbind the click?

```
$('#div').unbind('click');
```

Comment: `toggle` is not an event or an event handler. It is a convenience function that actually adds `click` handlers.

Comment: So I've just discovered. Unbinding the click event seems to work though. http://jsfiddle.net/finbarr/gePha/

Comment: exactly like my first comment on the OP's question said ;) ~~ "The best way is to unbind the click events that toggle adds. I'd post an answer, but I'm out of time right now". The answer I don't currently have time to post (I'm technically at work) was going to specifically just remove that particular event handler. Your answer removes all of them. For many projects, such a draconian method is fine though, so I up-voted your answer. I would add a warning to it though pointing out that this will remove *all* click handlers.

Comment: yeah, that works. I look forward to Ben Lee's "complete" answer, when he gets a chance to post it, but, for now, I am not too concerned. That particular #div has only one method attached to it, so removing that works just fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

You could put `condition` inside of the function:

```
$("#div").toggle(
    function() {
        if (condition) {
            //do this
        }
    },
    function() {
        if (condition) {
            //do that
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.cleanData()`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L735):

```
// this will destroy all data bound to that element
$.cleanData($("#div"));
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/UfLfa/1)

Comment: Your demo code doesn't seem to do anything. Also, what is that syntax supposed to mean?

Comment: @Ben Lee - comment out the last statement and clicking the divs will work again. It kills the `toggle()`.

Comment: Is cleanData documented anywhere? I'm googling it, but I can't find a page which explains what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Andrew Shephard - It is used internally for cleaning up data bound to elements, it is called 'under the hood' every time  you do `.html('')`, `.empty()` and so on, to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: It is part of the manipulation module. It is declared here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L735

Comment: It is used, within the same module, in the `.remove`, `.empty` and `.html` methods.

Comment: Can you explain what this syntax means? `$("#div").toggle(,);`? Specifically the `(,)`. I've never seen actual arguments simply blank, what does that mean?

Comment: @Ben Lee - I'm an idiot. I've removed that from my answer, as I realised, the reason it was working is because it was breaking JS :(

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way:

Remove the class that is selected for toggling. Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/leifparker/rSP34/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="button_toToggle"> Toggle it! </div>
<div class="button_disableToggle"> Disable Toggle </div>
<div class="happyDiv togglable">&nbsp;</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.button_toToggle').click(function(){
    $('.togglable').toggle();
});
$('.button_disableToggle').click(function(){
    $('.happyDiv').removeClass('togglable');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you weren't passing anonymous functions to `toggle()`, you could use the technique described [on this forum post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-reset-toggle-actions-once-user-click-on-clear-button) to unbind the events.

Comment: sadly, it doesn't work. It activates the toggle, but the unbind doesn't happen.